# React - convert object into array of objects with properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following object

```
"data":{  
         "name 1":"a",
          "name 2":"b",
          "name 3":"b",
        },
```

How can I convert to array of objects that will keep both the name and data "a", "b" so I can map and render compoents for each one passing in the both the name and data?

Comment: Please add the desired output

Comment: What's the expected output, or rather how do you plan to structure the result? Regardless, the solution most likely involves `Object.keys()`

Comment: I need to pass both the left and right data, if I use object keys I only get the data like b or a but I also need name 1 or name 2 with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a reduce function you can do the following to achieve your goal

```
Object.keys(data).reduce((array, key) => {
    return [...array, {key: data[key]}]
}, [])
```

[`Reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is a cool function that iterates and combine data into one single item (could be 1 object, array, integer, etc).

[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is a way to get each key from the current object and be able to iterate over each.

Answer (score 3):

The solution provided by Tall Paul will work perfectly but you can also use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). It states that

> The Object.entries() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property [key, value] pairs, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

so you can try something like this

```
let result = Object.entries(data);
result.map((item, index)=>{
      console.log('key is:- ', item[0], ' and value is:- ', item[1]); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get all the keys in the object in an array using `Object.keys` function and use `map` function to get the desired output.

This will convert to **array of objects** that will keep both the **name and data**.

```js
var data = {  
          "name 1":"a",
          "name 2":"b",
          "name 3":"b",
}
var res = Object.keys(data).map(function(name){
 var obj = {};
 obj[name] = data[name];
 return obj;
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

js native method u can use;

```js
var data = {  
     "name 1":"a",
      "name 2":"b",
      "name 3":"b",
    };
    var newObj = [...Object.values(data), ...Object.keys(data)]
    console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: OP wanted the name and value both in the response