# Make an array from object to iterate over it by *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular

I got response from my api it simple one record from my database.

```
  getFilledForm() {
    const reservation = this.hotels[0].reservation;
    this.accidentFormService.getAccidentForm(reservation).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.form = res;
          console.log('this.form: '+JSON.stringify(this.form));
       
        this.test = Object.keys(this.form).map(key => ({ type: key, value: this.form[key] }));
          console.log('this.test: ' +this.test);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
  }
```

this.form is a object and output looks like:

```
this.form: {"id":1,reservation":1234,"hotel_name":"BB Hotels"}
```

I tried to make an array but my array of objects looks like ( this.test )

```
this.test: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

after stringify

```
this.test: [{"type":"id","value":1},{"type":"reservation","value":null},{"type":"hotel_name","value":"BB Hotels"}]
```

I want output like: `"id":1` no `"type":"id","value":1`

How sould it be ? I want to make a table from output using `*ngFor`

-Edit
Added HTML

```
 <table *ngIf="checkForm" class="table table-sm align-items-center table-hover table-flush responsive">
               <thead class="thead-light">
                 <tr>
                   <th scope="col" class="lPart">ID</th>
                   <th scope="col" class="lPart">Hotel Name</th>
                 </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                 <tr
                   *ngFor="let form of form | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }; let i = index">
                   <td id="lPart">{{ form.id }}</td>
                   <td id="lPart">{{ form.hotel_name }}</td>
                 </tr>
               </tbody>
             </table>
```

Comment: This is very much a code smell.  Since the response is a single element, why do you need to iterate anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - convert object into array of objects with properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50740645/react-convert-object-into-array-of-objects-with-properties)

Comment: @Taplar if I want to use just this.form I got error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Comment: What did you get that error from?

Comment: from my table  *ngFor="let test of form

Comment: can you show your html code ?

Comment: edited question

Comment: `this.form = [res]` to turn the single result into an array that is iterable

Comment: Whaaaat? It was that simple? I see this first time

Comment: @MarkeZ Yes if you have only single object and want to convert it into an array you can just put object insite brackets like Taplar suggested, did you try did that work for you?